# How to simulate button click in Jest with Non-React Code

Tags: javascript, jestjs, jsdom

I have some snippets of Vanilla Javascript Code (with JQuery but no major front-end frameworks like React/Angular). The code looks like this

```
setupIconClickEvents() {
    $('#someButton').on('click', (e) => {
        callFunction(parameters);
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

I want to simulate the button click to test that the function was called, which I can do easily with a spy. However the function never gets hit inside. This is my current attempt

```
describe('setupIconClickEvents()', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
        object.setupIconClickEvents();
        document.body.innerHTML = `
            <div>
                <button id="someButton"></div>
            </div>
        `;
    });

    describe('rankIcon', () => {
        it('should stop event propagation', () => {
            jest.spyOn(object, 'callFunction');
            $('#someButton').trigger('click');
            expect(object.callFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

How can I get inside the snippet of code when I click my button?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I meant non-react code. I should have been more clear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are you sure that the code block where the trigger call is placed gets executed at all(trace it adding `console.log('hit')`; before the trigger line)?
2. Does the selector work(dump its result- `console.log($('#someButton'));`?- given that you generate the html dynamically it is a common mistake to mix the order of operations and try to select element that is not on the page.
3. Is there a click event on the button(**check the browser inspector events tab**)?

Answer (score 0):

I saw another answer for this, you could just test the function itself, a part from the html and in a selenium e2e test you make this kind of test not simulating a click but make the selenium drive really click on the buttom.